# Busboy seems to be causing an internal server error when requiring it in my uploadImage function for Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, postman, busboy

I've spent pretty much all day trying to figure out how to successfully upload photos into my storage and database, and so far I can't even get one to be successful!

Essentially I'm using postman to send a post request with an image file attached. I think I hit all the point as in I have the content type set to multipart/form-data, I have the body tab on form-data, and I have the row with my file set to file and not text.
[Photo of postman request and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6liuE.png)

And this internal server error is the issue that I can't resolve.

Now In my function below, I require busboy and at that point is where the internal server error occurs, if I place a return before that, then it will return. But if I place a return after this is declared, this error occurs.

```
const { admin, db } = require('../util/admin');
const config = require("../util/config");

...

exports.uploadImage = (req, res) => {

  // res.send("this worked"); // everything works up to this point

  const Busboy = require("busboy");

  const path = require("path");

  const os = require("os");

  const fs = require("fs");

  const busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });

  let imageToBeUploaded = {};
  let imageFileName;

  busboy.on("file", (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
    console.log(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype);
    if (mimetype !== "image/jpeg" && mimetype !== "image/png") {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: "Wrong file type submitted" });
    }
    // my.image.png => ['my', 'image', 'png']
    const imageExtension = filename.split(".")[filename.split(".").length - 1];
    // 32756238461724837.png
    imageFileName = `${Math.round(
      Math.random() * 1000000000000
    ).toString()}.${imageExtension}`;
    const filepath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), imageFileName);
    imageToBeUploaded = { filepath, mimetype };
    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filepath));

  });
  busboy.on("finish", () => {
    admin
      .storage()
      .bucket()
      .upload(imageToBeUploaded.filepath, {
        resumable: false,
        metadata: {
          metadata: {
            contentType: imageToBeUploaded.mimetype
          }
        }
      })
      .then(() => {
        const images = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${config.storageBucket}/o/${imageFileName}?alt=media`;
        return db.doc(`/posts/${req.params.postId}`).update({ images });
      })
      .then(() => {
        return res.json({ message: "image uploaded successfully" });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: "something went wrong" });
      });
  });
  busboy.end(req.rawBody);
};
```

And here's my index file included

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const app = require('express')();

const FBAuth = require('./util/fbAuth')

const { getAllPosts, createOnePost, getThePost, deletePost, uploadImage } = require('./handlers/posts');
const { login } = require('./handlers/users');

// Posts Routes

app.get('/posts', getAllPosts);
app.get('/post/:postId', getThePost);
app.post("/post", FBAuth, createOnePost);
app.delete('/post/:postId', FBAuth, deletePost);
app.post('/post/:postId/image', FBAuth, uploadImage);

//TODO update post

// Login Route

app.post('/login', login)

exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

The it seems there's something going on when I declare busboy in my function that is causing the error. And I have no idea why.

I should mention that the code seemed to run when I was using a localhost with "$ firebase serve", but the jpeg images weren't really showing up in the firestorage.

I really appreciate any help you all can offer, and please feel free to ask for more information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything in the code that would be causing an internal server error. I imagine you don't actually have busboy installed with npm. Have you gone into your functions folder and typed "npm install busboy"?

Comment: Yep, ok the problem was this: I typed npm install busboy in the root directory and forgot to go into my functions folder like you specified. Thank you!